# How would I make a simple indicator program to record timestamps?

Tags: application-development, indicator

I would like to make a button to sit up next to my sound/wireless/etc indicators which, when toggled, will change color and write the system time with the word "begin" to a file, then, when toggled again, return to its original color and record the system time with the word "end."  Ideally, the button would maintain it's toggled/untoggled state even if the system restarts.

I can't imagine this would be a difficult program to make at all, but I am a bit new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure how to make a program work as an indicator, or how to make something maintain its state on system restart.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/sagarchalise/My-Ubuntu-Unity-Indicators/blob/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Porting_Guide_for_Applications) (specially the Python version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got interested so here is my Python code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import time, ctime
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as Indicator


MY_FILENAME = '/home/your-username/myfile.log'
MY_INDICATOR_ID = 'my-indicator-example'
STOP_ICON_NAME = 'indicator-messages'
START_ICON_NAME = 'indicator-messages-new'

class MyIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.indicator = Indicator.Indicator.new(
                                MY_INDICATOR_ID,
                                STOP_ICON_NAME,
                                Indicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)

        self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.indicator.set_attention_icon(START_ICON_NAME)

        self.has_started = False

        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()

        start_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Start')
        start_item.connect('activate', self.start_activated, filename)
        self.menu.append(start_item)
        start_item.show()

        stop_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Stop')
        stop_item.connect('activate', self.stop_activated, filename)
        self.menu.append(stop_item)
        stop_item.show()

        self.indicator.set_menu(self.menu)

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

    def start_activated (self, menu_item, filename):
        if not self.has_started:
            myfile = open(filename, 'a')
            myfile.write('Start  <%s>\n' % ctime(time()))
            self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ATTENTION)
            self.has_started = True

    def stop_activated (self, menu_item, filename):
        if self.has_started:
            myfile = open(filename, 'a')
            myfile.write('End    <%s>\n' % ctime(time()))
            self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
            self.has_started = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    indicator = MyIndicator(MY_FILENAME)
    indicator.main()
```

I used the info given by [gpaste-indicator](https://github.com/sagarchalise/My-Ubuntu-Unity-Indicators/blob/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator) and the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Porting_Guide_for_Applications).
I'm not sure about the "keeping the state between restarts" feature, the simplest would be to read the last line of `myfile.log` and setting `self.has_started` accordingly.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This code has been very instructive to me.

Comment: I was able to massage your code to do everything I wanted.  I'll post the full app as a separate answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to modify and improve the code from edwin's very helpful answer so that the app does keep state between restarts!  I'm using it all the time now.

For anyone else who wants to use it, here it is (also available [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UpiSPstv)):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import time, ctime
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as Indicator
from datetime import datetime, date


MY_FILENAME = '/home/anotherghost/workhours.log'
MY_INDICATOR_ID = 'work-hours-indicator'
STOP_ICON_NAME = 'indicator-messages'
START_ICON_NAME = 'indicator-messages-new'
FMT = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"

class MyIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.indicator = Indicator.Indicator.new(
                                MY_INDICATOR_ID,
                                STOP_ICON_NAME,
                                Indicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)

        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()

        start_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Start')
        start_item.connect('activate', self.start_activated, filename)
        self.menu.append(start_item)
        start_item.show()

        stop_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Stop')
        stop_item.connect('activate', self.stop_activated, filename)
        self.menu.append(stop_item)
        stop_item.show()

        showall_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Show all')
        showall_item.connect('activate', self.showall, filename)
        self.menu.append(showall_item)
        showall_item.show()

        self.indicator.set_menu(self.menu)
        self.indicator.set_attention_icon(START_ICON_NAME)

        with open(MY_FILENAME,'r') as fn:
            try:
                fn.seek(-70, 2)
            except (IndexError, IOError):
                fn.seek(max(-len(fn.read().decode()),-69),2)
            self.last = fn.readlines()[-1].decode()
            if len(self.last) > 1 and len(self.last) < 30:
                self.last = self.last.split(" ")
                self.last[-1] = self.last[-1][:4]
                self.last = " ".join(self.last)
                self.start_time = datetime.strptime(self.last, FMT)
                self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ATTENTION)
                self.has_started = True
                self.end_time = datetime.now()
            else:
                self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
                self.has_started = False
                self.start_time = datetime.now()
                self.end_time = datetime.now()


    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

    def start_activated (self, menu_item, filename):
        if not self.has_started:
            myfile = open(filename, 'a')
            self.start_time = datetime.now()
            myfile.write('%s' % self.start_time.strftime(FMT))
            self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ATTENTION)
            self.has_started = True
            myfile.close()

    def stop_activated (self, menu_item, filename):
        if self.has_started:
            myfile = open(filename, 'r+')
            myfile.seek(-1, 2)
            if myfile.read(1) == '\n':
                myfile.seek(-1, 2)
            self.end_time = datetime.now()
            self.elapsed_time = self.end_time - self.start_time
            myfile.write('\t%s\t' % self.end_time.strftime(FMT))
            myfile.write('%s\n' % round(float(self.elapsed_time.seconds)/3600,3) )
            self.indicator.set_status(Indicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
            self.has_started = False
            myfile.close()

    def showall (self, menu_item, filename):
        myfile = open('op.log', 'a')
        myfile.write('has_started: %s\n' % self.has_started)
        myfile.write('start_time: %s\n' % self.start_time.strftime(FMT))
        myfile.write('end_time: %s\n' % self.end_time.strftime(FMT))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    indicator = MyIndicator(MY_FILENAME)
    indicator.main()
```

Comment: **+1** Good job!

Comment: But you should edit the code you've paste, try not using tab characters for the indentation instead use four spaces (you can configure that in GEdit).

Comment: @edwin Got it, done.